# MongoDB: is a $lt comparison of String ID equivalent to an ObjectID comparison?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, aggregation-framework

So I store the ObjectId of a `post` inside a `comment` BSON. An example of my BSON schema is as follows:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("570175e6c002e46edb92aaa5"), "userid" : "56f3f70d4de8c74a69d1d5e1", "postid" : "5700edfe03fcdb000347beaa" }
```

Now, I want to find all the posts below the postid `5700edfe03fcdb000347bebc`.

So I go:

```
"$match" : {
            "postid" : {
                "$lt" : "5700edfe03fcdb000347bebc"
            }
}
```

However, the $lt aggregation operator is comparing a `String ID` instead of an `ObjectID` and the results returned is still accurate. So, if this is a list of my postids:

```
{ "_id" : "5700edfe03fcdb000347beda" }
{ "_id" : "5700edfe03fcdb000347bebf" }
{ "_id" : "5700edfe03fcdb000347bebc" }
{ "_id" : "5700edfe03fcdb000347bebb" }
{ "_id" : "5700edfe03fcdb000347beaa" }
{ "_id" : "5700edfb03fcdb000347bebe" }
{ "_id" : "5700edfb03fcdb000347beba" }
```

It will return:

```
{ "_id" : "5700edfe03fcdb000347bebb" }
{ "_id" : "5700edfe03fcdb000347beaa" }
{ "_id" : "5700edfb03fcdb000347bebe" }
{ "_id" : "5700edfb03fcdb000347beba" }
```

However, I wonder if this will always be true or was the above just luck?

I understand that sorting ObjectID will always return an accurate result because inside an ObjectId is a timestamp so it can use the timestamp to sort ObjectId accurately. Inside a string, there is no timestamp so will it sort accurately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongo uses ASCII-betically string comparison, which is case sensitive. In this case, that will work, but thinking in performance area - it is slow.

As objectId field is a 12bit object, so it string equivalent in string will take more space, having two documents

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("575f2aa031dcfb59af388e1f"),
    "a" : 2.0,
    "id" : "575f2a5731dcfb59af388e1e"
},{
    "_id" : ObjectId("575f2ab031dcfb59af388e21"),
    "a" : 3.0,
    "id" : ObjectId("575f2ab031dcfb59af388e20")
}
```

and checking size:

```
Object.bsonsize(db.test.findOne({a:2})) // returns 66
Object.bsonsize(db.test.findOne({a:3})) // returns 49
```

gives 17 bytes less when using objeciId.

Is the game worth a deal? Yes, when field is indexed - index file is smaller => faster, less reads, more performance